# How to find the shortest simple path in a Tree in a linear time?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm

Here is a problem from Algorithms book by Vazirani

> The input to this problem is a tree T with integer weights on the edges. The weights may be negative,
>   zero, or positive. Give a linear time algorithm to find the shortest simple path in T. The length of a
>   path is the sum of the weights of the edges in the path. A path is simple if no vertex is repeated. Note
>   that the endpoints of the path are unconstrained.
>
> HINT: This is very similar to the problem of finding the largest independent set in a tree.

How can I solve this problem in linear time?

Here is my algorithm but I'm wonder if it is linear time since it is nothing different than depth-first:

> 1. Traverse tree (depth-first)
> 2. Keep the indexes (nodes)
> 3. add the values
> 4. do (1) till the end of tree
> 5. compare the sum and print the path and sum

this problem is similar this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792865/how-to-minimize-total-cost-of-shortest-path-tree) but there is no certain answer.

Comment: Vazirani approximation book? I can't understand problem, every edge in tree is path, and smallest edge is shortest path, would you clarify me by this, or say exact name of problem too google it? did you mean finding shortest path tree? or root of tree?

Comment: @Saeed - the smallest edge is not necessarily the shortest path, because you can have negative weights.

Comment: what about empty path - it is the shortest, isn't it? You haven't put a single requirement of what tha path should contain. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Tomas Empty path has weight zero. A path consisting of a single negative weight edge is shorter.

Comment: The HINT says that this problem is related to finding the largest independent set in a tree. Any thoughts on what that means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem is pretty much equivalent to the [minimum sum subsequence problem](http://wordaligned.org/articles/the-maximum-subsequence-problem), and can be solved in a similar manner by dynamic programming.

We will calculate the following arrays by using DF searches:

```
dw1[i] = minimum sum achievable by only using node i and its descendants.
pw1[i] = predecessor of node i in the path found for dw1[i].
dw2[i] = second minimum sum achevable by only using node i and its descendants,
         a path that is edge-disjoint relative to the path found for dw1[i].
```

If you can calculate these, take `min(dw1[k], dw1[k] + dw2[k])` over all `k`. This is because your path will take one of these basic shapes:

```
  k              k
  |     or     /   \
  |           /     \
  |
```

All of which are covered by the sums we're taking.

**Calculating dw1**

Run a DFS from the root node. In the DFS, keep track of the current node and its father. At each node, assume its children are `d1, d2, ... dk`. Then `dw1[i] = min(min{dw1[d1] + cost[i, d1], dw1[d2] + cost[i, d2], ..., dw1[dk] + cost[i, dk]}, min{cost[i, dk]})`. Set `dw1[i] = 0` for leaf nodes. Don't forget to update `pw1[i]` with the selected predecessor.

**Calculating dw2**

Run a DFS from the root node. Do the same thing you did for `dw1`, except when going from a node `i` to one of its children `k`, only update `dw2[i]` if `pw1[i] != k`. You call the function recursively for all children however. It would look something like this in pseudocode:

```
df(node, father)
    dw2[node] = inf
    for all children k of node
        df(k, node)

        if pw1[node] != k
            dw2[node] = min(dw2[node], dw1[k] + cost[node, k], cost[node, k])
```

Comment: Looks promising but I have a few suggestions: (1) Under "Calculating dw1" when you say "descendants" I believe you mean "children" ("descendants" usually means all children and children's children, recursively); (2) The calculation of each of `dw1[i]`, `dw2[i]` and `up[i]` should include 0 in the `min{...}` operation to allow the path to terminate there (so that for example a tree containing no negative-length edges will return a score of 0); (3) I believe your calculation of `dw2[i]` should exclude the optimal edge leading...

Comment: ... from vertex `i` only, but at lower levels should include optimal edges (ask if you need clarification); (4) `up[i]` calculations can be simplified by noting that every path is of 1 of 2 kinds: either it is "straight down" or it contains an "uppermost corner" (a vertex v such that the parent of v is not in the path) -- any path containing an uppermost corner at some vertex v will be found by considering `dw1[v] + dw2[v]`, so `up[i]` only needs to calculate costs on a straight path back towards the root (i.e. `up[i]` will be the minimum cost of a "straight-down" path ending at `i`).

Comment: @j_random_hacker - (1) agreed, will update. (2) you mean a null path? I would consider a path to contain at least one edge, that's why I didn't add 0. It's easy enough to modify if the OP wants to accept null paths. (3) isn't that what happens? We're dealing with a tree, so if you exclude the optimal edge leading from `i`, you automatically exclude the rest as well. (4) I'm not sure what you mean here. In my solution, `up` doesn't store only straight paths from `i` to the root. If you do that, how will you get your answer? Becase the minimum mustn't necessarily be a straight path.

Comment: More on (3) - if you mean the check shouldn't be done on lower levels, I think that's wrong, because then you will have overlapping min-cost and second min-cost paths for some descendants. They must be edge-disjoint for every node, otherwise you'll get wrong answers when doing `dw1[k] + dw2[k]`, because the two paths will share common edges.

Comment: @IVlad: (2) Indeed, including a 0 under the `min()` will allow null paths, but leaving it out completely will force all paths to end at a leaf -- definitely not what's wanted.  If you want to allow paths that end before a leaf, but forbid null paths, this is certainly possible but requires keeping more scores for each node I think.  (3) Not true -- remember it's a *tree*, so if you have 2 downward paths starting at v whose first edges are different, they will necessarily have no common vertices (except for v). ...

Comment: ... So having `dw2[i]` avoid the optimal down-edge at level `i` is sufficient to guarantee that the down-paths represented by `dw1[i]` and `dw2[i]` are vertex-disjoint apart from `i`; avoiding optimal down-edges for `dw2[i]` *at each level* just makes `dw2[i]` worse than it needs to be.

Comment: (4) I'm saying you can (and I think should) let `up` store only straight-up paths from `i`, because the case that you're worried about (when you say the minimum mustn't necessarily be a straight path) will be handled as follows: Suppose that the minimum path through vertex u goes through the edge to u's parent but is not "straight up". In that case, there is some vertex v above (closer to the root than) u which is the "uppermost corner" of this path, and when we scan through all vertices looking for the best path through each, we will find this path when we look at vertex v. Clear?

Comment: In fact now that I think about it, `up` isn't needed at all if null paths are allowed, since any "straight-down" path is equivalent to a path with an "uppermost corner" in which one of the 2 "spokes" from that corner vertex is a null path. :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker - true about (2). I think we can avoid null paths by also considering taking the single min-cost edge alone. Basically run minimum sum subsequence on the edges. This way the paths won't necessarily start and end at a leaf. As for (3), can you post some pseudocode? The function calls itself recursively for each child, and the paths ending at that child must also be edge-disjoint. `dw2[i]` won't be worse than it needs to be, because you will be using the `dw1` of `i` 's children to compute it.

Comment: "because you will be using the `dw1` of `i` 's children to compute it" -- OK it sounds like you're already doing what I'm suggesting then.  The description in your post could be read as saying that `dw2` is computed recursively *using `dw2`*, which would give the suboptimality I was worried about.  Maybe you could mention that the calculation for `dw2[i]` reverts to using `dw1[i]` on the children in the post?

Comment: Looking good, +1 at last :-P  But do you see that `up` can be eliminated entirely by changing the overall answer for a node `k` to `min(dw1[k], dw2[k], dw1[k] + dw2[k])`?  This changes the overall interpretation of the query on a node `q` from "What is the shortest path containing `q`?" to "What is the shortest path whose highest node is `q`?" -- but that's OK, because every path has a highest node.  :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker - I just realized that while you wrote your comment and got rid of it :). Is putting `dw2[k]` in the minimum necessary? It will never be smaller than `dw1[k]`. Some time ago I solved a problem which asked queries such as `what's the shortest path containing q?`, so I was set on using `up`. Realize it's not needed here though.

Comment: Good point, `dw2[k]` isn't needed in the minimum as it can't be less than `dw1[k]`.  Simpler and simpler!

Comment: @j_random_hacker Any thoughts on what is the relationship between this problem and finding the largest independent set in a tree, as advertised in the hint?

Comment: @becko: I don't actually see much connection I'm afraid...  I do know that independent set in a tree can be solved in a broadly similar way, by calculating 2 values for each node with a DFS: the size of the largest independent set in the subtree rooted at node i that uses node i, and the size of the largest independent set in the subtree rooted at node i that doesn't.  Call these x(i) and y(i) respectively.  Then you can calculate x(i) by taking 1 + sum(y(j)) for each child j of i, and you can calculate y(i) by taking sum(x(j)) for each child j of i.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Thanks. Maybe that is the connection. Nice algorithm, by the way.

Comment: @becko: Just noticed a bug! y(i) should be sum(max(x(j), y(j))) for each child j of i, since we only want to allow, not require, that the children are included in the independent set.