# Graph theory: Breadth First Search

Tags: c++, graph-theory

There are n vertices connected by m edges. Some of the vertices are special and others are ordinary. There is atmost one path to move from one vertex to another.

First Query:
I need to find out how many pairs of special vertices exists which are connected directly or indirectly.

My approach:
I"ll apply BFS (via queue )to see how many nodes are connected to each other somehow. Let number of special vertices I discover in this be n, then answer to my query would be nC2. I'll repeat this till all vertices are visited.

Second Query:
How many vertices lie on path between any two special vertices.

My approach:
In my approach for query 1, I'll apply BFS to find out path between any two special vertices and then backtrack and mark the vertices lying on the path.

Problem:
Number of vertices can be as high as 50,000. So, applying BFS and then I guess, backtracking would be slower for my time constraint (2 seconds).

I have list of all vertices and their adjacency list. Now while pushing vertices in my queue while BFS, can I somehow calculate answer to query 2 also? Is there a better approach one can use to solve the problem? Input format will be such that I'll be told whether a vertex is special or not one by one and then I'll be given info about i th pathway which connects two vertices.There is atmost one path to move from one vertex to another.

Comment: At most 1 path to move from 1 vertex to another --> the graph is a tree or a forest.

Comment: Those people downvoting, what's the problem?  Looks like a good question to me.

Comment: The graph is a forest

Comment: what is a `special` vertex ?

Comment: I fail to understand why people are down voting this. It's not that I'm asking for solution to the problem without any effort from my side.

Comment: Its just that some vertices are termed "special" and others are termed "ordinary". It doesn't have any special relation to anything.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_off-line_lowest_common_ancestors_algorithm

Comment: As for implementation, you might take a look at igraph: http://igraph.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I only need the numbers(count) and not the indices of the vertices.

Comment: People are probably downvoting because this is a competition problem from here: http://www.codechef.com/FEB14/problems/DRGHTS

Answer (score 0):

The first query is solved by splitting your forest in trees.

Starting with the full set of vertices, pick the one, then visit every node you can from there, until you cannot visit any more vertex. This is one tree. Repeat for each tree.

You now have K bags of vertices, each containing 0-j special ones. That answers the first question.

For the second question, I suppose a trivial solution is indeed to BFS the path between a vertex to another for each pair in their sub-graph.

You could also take advantage of the tree nature of your sub-graph. This question: [How to find the shortest simple path in a Tree in a linear time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977112/how-to-find-the-shortest-simple-path-in-a-tree-in-a-linear-time) mentions it. (I have not really dug into this yet, though)

Comment: Would splitting my forest in trees using BFS via queue, be fine and fast enough?

Comment: splitting the forest in trees is o(n). You simply visit all nodes, each only once. I don't see how it could be faster (i.e. how could you split the forest without visiting each node at least once?)

Comment: For the 2nd problem, I don't think this is fast enough. But this also depends on the number of queries; if the number of queries is large, around 10^3, then it is going to fail..

Comment: Yes, I don't feel we can do better than O(n) for query 1.

Comment: Number of vertices can be at max 50,000

Comment: as for question 2, there are optimisations, such as cutting the leaves from the tree until you cannot remove a leaf without removing a special vertex. This operation is slow o(n) for each level, but can significantly speed up the BFS after that.

Comment: If I remove all leaves from my tree then I will be left with special and ordinary vertices. Then each ordinary vertex will lie on path between any two special vertices in the tree. So, I'll get answer to my query 2. I only want the number and not the indexes

Answer (score 0):

For the first query, one round of BFS and some simple calculation as you have described is optimal.

For the second query, assuming the worst case where all vertices are special and the graph is a tree, doing a BFS per query is going to give O(Q|V|) complexity, where Q is the number of queries. You are going to run into trouble if Q is larger than 10<sup>4</sup> and |V| is also larger than 10<sup>4</sup>.

In the worst case, we are basically solving the all pairs shortest path problem, but on a tree/forest. When |V| is small, we can do BFS on all nodes, which results in O(|V|<sup>2</sup>) algorithm. However, there is a faster algorithm:

- Read all second type queries and store all the pairs in a set S.
- For each tree in the forest:

  - Choose a root node for the current tree. Calculate the distance from the root node to all the other nodes in the current tree (regardless it is special or not).
  - Calculating lowest common ancestor (LCA) for all pairs of nodes being queried (which are stored in set S). This can be done with [Tarjan's offline LCA algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_off-line_lowest_common_ancestors_algorithm).
  - Calculate the distance between a pair of node by: `dist(root, a) + dist(root, b) - dist(root, lca(a,b))`

Comment: If I somehow manage to remove all leaves from my tree, won't I"ll be left with only special vertices and ordinary vertices where each ordinary vertex will lie on path between two special vertices for sure?

Comment: @CPPCoder: I didn't tell you to remove all leaves from your tree, though it might help a bit to speed up. The algorithm I layout for the 2nd problem doesn't care whether a node is special or not.

Comment: Actually I only need "how many". Will removing leaves from my tree be slower?

Answer (score 0):

Let the arr be bool array where arr[i] is 1 if it is special and 0 otherwise.
find-set(i) returns the root node of the tree. So any nodes lying in the same tree returns the same number.

```
for(int i=1; i<n; i++){ 
      for(int j=i+1; j<=n; j++){
            if(arr[i]==1 && arr[j]==1){        //If both are special
                if(find-set(i)==find-set(j)){  //and both i and j belong to the same tree
                    //k++ where k is answer to the first query.
                    //bfs(i,j) and find the intermediate vertices and do ver[i]=1 for the corresponding intermediate vertex/node.
                }
            }
      }        
}
```

finally count no of 1's in ver matrix which is the answer to the second query.