# Find Minimum Weight of Simple Path in Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, shortest-path

I ran into a problem, we want to design an efficient algorithm for finding a simple path with lightest weight. (simple path with minimum weights).

i think this is not polynomial solution, but some friends say may be O(n) or O(n^2) or O(n lg n) would be... !

programmers or expert man, would help me? any pesudocode?

EDIT:

The input to this problem is a tree T with integer weights on the edges. The weights may be negative, zero, or positive. The length of a path is the sum of the weights of the edges in the path. A path is simple if no vertex is repeated.

Output: finding the least weights simple path in a given tree.

Comment: what the path would be ? root node -> any leaf node ?

Comment: Dear @RatulSharker, just we know, we want to find simple path with the lightest weight. the length of a path is the sum of edges weight.

Comment: In tree which is graph? Simple path is path is path which doesn't pass through the same vertex twice? Will it be zero length path, or path consisting of lightest edge? May be there is some additional conditions?

Comment: maybe you are right.

Comment: Ah, got it, path can consist from several negative weight edges, and even some positive, if they allow to build long negative weight path.

Comment: yes, can we find it in a polynomial time?

Comment: Dear @RatulSharker, maybe a path contains root to leaf...

Comment: @AliMovagher Of course there is a polynomial solution. Bellman Ford works for any graphs with no negative cycles, and every tree is included. There is however most likely an even more efficient solution than BF.

Comment: the smallest edge is not necessarily the shortest path...

Comment: If you specify the path as root -> leaf, you can run DFS (Depth first search). When running DFS you can maintain the length traversed to that node from root. when a leaf node reached you save the length of that leaf as the minimum. Then when second leaf is reached you compare the lenght of second leaf with the previous one, save the minium path length & this process continues with all the other leaf nodes. then you will find the minimum length path. If you wish to find the path you can also store the path with the current minimum lenght

Comment: traversing DFS will cost you O(m+n) where m is the number of node, n is the number of edges. All other operation according to comparison is O(1).

Comment: the smallest edge is not necessarily the shortest path, because you can have negative weights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pseudo code of a linear solution:

```
res = 0 // A path from a node to itself has a weight 0

// Runs depth first search from the v vertex and returns the weight of
// the shortest path that starts in a descendant of v and ends in v
def dfs(v):
    // The shortest path from a descendant of v to v
    minLength = 0
    // The list of all lengths of paths coming from children
    childLengths = []
    for edge in edges(v):
        childLength = dfs(edge.to)
        // Update the result with a vertical path from the child
        res = min(res, childLength + edge.weight) 
        // Update the minLength based on the child's value
        minLength = min(minLength, childLength + edge.weight)
        childLengths.add(childLength + edge.weight)
    if childLengths.size() >= 2:
        // Update the result based on two smallest children values.
        // Finds the the first and the second minimum in a list in a linear time.
        min1 = firstMin(childLengths)
        min2 = secondMin(childLengths)
        res = min(res, min1 + min2)
    return minLength    

dfs(root)
return res
```

If the tree is not rooted, we can pick any vertex as a root.

Comment: any implementation for Test online?

Comment: @AliMovagher No, I do not have a ready implementation. But it should be easy to convert this pseudo code to a concrete programming language.

Answer (score 0):

In a tree there is only one simple path between every pair of nodes ([there's a proof here](http://compalg.inf.elte.hu/~tony/Oktatas/TDK/FINAL/Chap%204.PDF)).

So, even if you try every pair of nodes finding the path between then, you would have an O(n^3) algorithm.

One better way is to find, for every node the cost to every other node in a single visit. This lowers the algorithm to O(n^2).

Comment: what about linear time algorithms?

Comment: would u please describe me what is  the difference between my question and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977112/how-to-find-the-shortest-simple-path-in-a-tree-in-a-linear-time?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple O(n) algorithm which is based on that fact that in a tree there are always some leaves and if we delete a leaf the remaining graph is still tree. So we can delete leaves one by one, and process all the tree (all the edges) by this way.

You will need to keep lightest path found for every node.

So let's suppose you are processing some leaf and node n is node leaf is connected to, and we want to be sure that you are keeping an eye over any path which passes through edge which connects this n and leaf. Let's look at picture

[image]

The direction here means only direction from nodes that are deletes earlier to their "parents", node which will be deleted later, it may depend on order n which you are processing leaves.

If we have shortest path which passes through the leaf and n it can ether connect any "child" of leaf with some other child of n or it can connect any "child" of leaf to the rest of the tree.

In both cases it's enough to keep shortest path from any of already processed nodes to current node. When we are processing leaf we take lightest path founded for leaf and add weight of connection to it and compare it to shortest path already saved for n. In such way we inevitably will come to comparing two shortest paths for n and will be able to unite them and will have shortest path for n saved when all "children" of n will be processed.

So here is pseudo-code.

```
for each (node in graph)
{
   node.shortest_path = 0; //zero length path from this node to this node
}
leaves = new list(all leaves in graph); //O(n) to find
int minWeight = 0; //any zero length path is minimum weight path currently found

//note that we a going to add new elements in list during the iteration
//and we will need to iterate through all of them including new added
//so in usual programming languages you will need to use for cycle
for each (leaf in leaves)
{
       //we will have last node in tree with no connection
       //because we will delete it on previous iteration
       //and we don't need to process this node
       //for this problem it is last node, 
       //but it may be not last if we have several trees instead of one
       if (no point connected to leaf) continue; 

     n = only one node still connected to leaf       
     connection = connection between n and leaf

     //check if we can make a short path which goes through n 
     //from one already processed "child" node to another
     if (leaf.shortest_path + 
         connection.weight 
         + n.shortest_path < minWeight  )
     {
         minWeight = leaf.shortest_path+connection.weight+n.shortest_path; 
     }
     //and we need to keep lightest path from any processed "child" to n
     if (leaf.shortest_path + connection.weight < n.shortest_path )
     {
          n.shortest_path = leaf.shortest_path + connection.weight;
          if(n.shortest_path < minWeight )
          {
               minWeight = n.shortest_path;
          }
     }

     //delete connection and 
     connection.delete();
     //if n is now leaf add it to leaf list
     if (n is leaf) 
     {
         leaves.Add(n);
     }
}
```

So in main cycle we processed each node exactly once so we have O(n) complexity.
If you need nonzero length path but this algorithm didn't find it, it means that all edges have positive weight and lightest non zero length path is lightest edge.

Comment: If this code section actually works for positive length, then try to increment all edges length with the positive value of the minimum length edge. say (-x)  is the minimum length in the tree, then add length (x) for all edges with their existing length. If no negative length are present set (x)'s value to zero or no need to increment at all. Whenever the solution found, subtract (x) from each edge which are selected as the resulted minimum path.

Comment: In tree with three nodes and two edges with weights -4 and -8 lightest path consists of both edges and has weight -12 , if we add 6 to each weight we will have two edges with weights 2 and -2 and lightest path will consist of 1 edge with weight -2. We do not always get equivalent by incrementing all edges by the same value.

Comment: the (x) would be the lowest negative value, in your example value 8 will be added each. which causing the length to be 0 & 4. Omitting 0 cause they don't adding any extra cost the path would be the value 4+0 = 4. there are two edge & subtracting 8 from each edge will result (4- 8) + (0-8) = -12. which is the minimum length.

Comment: My code section works for arbitrary integer weights tree, in a tree with only positive edges the minimum weight path is either 0 if path with no edges is allowed, or weight of lightest edge. In second case, lightest path in a tree with two edges of weight 4 and 0 the lightest path weights 0 and consists only of second edge.